# react-media-recorder does not work on Safari?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, safari

I'm trying to build a voice recording app in React that works both on Chrome and Safari.

I'm currently using react-media-recorder to record the audio.

On Chrome, it works perfectly. However on Safari, the audio seems to get recorded but does not play. It's strange because the browser indicates that it is playing sound but no sound comes out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-voicerecorder-lmeoq : playing the audio works on Chrome but not Safari.

How should I make this work ? I'm also open to changing library. I would be super thankful for a minimal code example that records and plays audios in Safari.

I've also a recorder that use directly MediaRecorder api but I can never make it work on Safari.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/0x006F/react-media-recorder/issues/124

Comment: I've tried several mimeType values but couldn't find one that works on Safari.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well, so far haven't found a solution after googling a bunch.

Comment: I am seeing this exact same issue. Did anyone solve this?

Comment: I was hoping to launch my app this week. but I forgot that Safari is the new IE.